# single table inheritance subclass doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to play around with association tables as well as single table inheritance ('STI'). I have a Man, Woman, and a Relationship model. The Relationship model has a type column, so that I can use STI. I also created a Friend model that inherits from Relationship, as Friend will be one type of relationship.

Man.rb

```
   attr_accessible :name
   has_many :relationships
   has_many :women, :through => :relationships
```

Woman.rb

```
attr_accessible :name
has_many :relationships
has_many :men,  :through => :relationships
```

In the meetup model, I also wish to keep track of when and where the date took place.

Relationship.rb

```
   attr_accessible :type
   belongs_to :woman
   belongs_to :man
```

Friend.rb

```
class Friend < Relationship

end
```

However, when I try to create a relationship with type friend, I get the warning message that the subclass doesn't exist. In the console, I'm doing this

```
     sarah = Woman.create!(name: 'Sarah')
     jim = Man.create!(name: 'Jim')

     jim.relationships.build(type: 'Friend', woman_id: 1)
=> #<Relationship id: nil, type: "Friend", man_id: 1, woman_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

     jim.save!
```

but then when I try to pull up the relationships for jim, I get

```
>> jim.relationships
  Relationship Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."man_id" = 1
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'friends'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Relationship.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.
```

The same is true when I try to create the relationship with 'friends' instead of 'Friend'

```
 jim.relationships.build(type: 'friends', woman_id: 1)
```

can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

I didn't create a table in the db for friends. I thought everything could be stored in the Relationship model. Since this is just a play-around app, I only assigned the type attribute for the Relationship model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the type value needs to be be lower case and singular - `friend` ?

but really you probably want to use the objects and let rails handle that for you

```
sarah = Woman.create!(name: 'Sarah')
jim = Man.create!(name: 'Jim')
Friend.create!(women: sarah, man: jim)
```

the Man Women models don't make sense to me - they are both a Person and a relationship should just have 2 people, regardless of gender

Comment: regarding the Man/Woman issue, I guess you're right, but i'm just experimenting to learn associations and STI. Your answer seems to ignore that I'm also trying to use STI.

Comment: `Friend` is an STI object and should save a record in the relationships table with the type automatically set to the sub-type